# Having trouble sending SLURM jobs to remotely connected clusters

Tags: mariadb, slurm, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating a SLURM multi-cluster setup, with a slurmdbd MariaDB database on premises and some number of slurmctld's in Oracle Cloud that are meant to receive jobs from the on-premise cluster. So far, I have connected the slurmctld's in the cloud to the database. They appear on the "sacctmgr list cluster" and I am able to receive info on them and delete jobs in their queues from the on-premise slurmctld. However, I am not able to send jobs from the on-premise cluster to these cloud clusters. When I try to submit jobs to the other clusters using -M  or -M all, they instead run on the on-premise queue.  The cloud clusters are able to run jobs directly submitted to them using sbatch.

There is an error that appears when I submit jobs. It is in the /var/log/slurmctld.log of the cluster that is supposed to receive the jobs:

```
[2022-03-17T19:15:41.046] Registering slurmctld at port 6817 with slurmdbd <IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>
[2022-03-17T19:15:41.046] error: slurmdbd: Sending message type DBD_REGISTER_CTLD: 11: Resource temporarily unavailable
[2022-03-17T19:15:46.046] error: g_slurm_auth_pack: protocol_version 6500 not supported
[2022-03-17T19:15:46.046] error: slurm_send_node_msg: authentication: No error
[2022-03-17T19:15:46.046] error: slurm_persist_conn_open: failed to send persistent connection init message to <IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>
```

I confirmed that the IP address and port are correct and connect to the slurmdbd, but what does the rest mean? I can't find any documentation and this issue doesn't seem to have come up on other forums in the past. What should I do to be able to actually send jobs to these clusters?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just the other way around: I couldn't sent jobs to my OCI Slurm instance.

For me the problem was: The OCI Slurm was a slurmdbd 20.11 and my on premise slurmctld was 21.08. The Problem is, that the slurmdbd has to be the same version or newer then the slurmctld (within at max 3 versions) and the rest of the of binaries. See the slides [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/SLUG21/Field_Notes_5.pdf) (Section Upgrading).

After upgrading the OCI Slurm instance, I could submit in both directions.

Comment: My slurmdbd is version 21.08, and my OCI Slurmctld's are version 20.02 . It should be working normally as it is within 3 versions, but I will still try upgrading the slurmctlds anyway to see if they work better.

Comment: That means that the OCIs slurmctld can talk to your slurmdbd, but your slurmctld cannot talk to the OCIs slurmdbd. So if you want to send jobs from your on prem cluster to the OCI, it will not work.